# Repulsion of charges

Tags: forces

Why is the repulsion between the charges is less when they are arranged on the surface of a conductor but it is not when they were in the bulk?

Answer (score 1):

The repulsion between excessive charges on the surface of a conductor is not necessarily lower than in the bulk. For instance we could, in theory, distribute the charges evenly over a large volume with much greater distances between the charges than on the surface.

The reason, the charges end up on the surface is because, while they are in the bulk they can move, but when they get to the surface they have no further way to go, since it would take a lot of energy for a charge to escape from a conductor.

Comment: When they are in the surface why can't they move again inwards inside the metal?

Comment: @RifatSafin Because, given a positive curvature of the surface (convex surface), the net force acting on an electron, located on the surface, from all other excessive electrons is pointing outward.

Comment: but if the surface is concave then what will happen ???.....can the electrons again indulge themselves into the bulk???

Comment: if we don't give any excess charges on the metal surface will the free electrons of the metal also lie on the metal surface due to repulsion?

Comment: @RifatSafin The surface cannot be concave everywhere, so the excessive electrons will concentrate at the convex parts of the surface or at the tips. In the absence of excessive charges, repulsion and attraction forces, acting on all electrons, are balanced, so they have no incentive to move beyond their neighborhood. If they did, they would create imbalance and would be immediately pulled back.

Comment: @RifatSafin No problem. Happy to help.

Comment: @RifatSafin An excessive electron in the bulk does not actually move all the way to  the surface, it rather pushes an electron in front of it and so forth. So, it is more of a shift, with multiple electrons involved. This is similar to how electrons flows in a circuit: they push each other rather than passing other electrons.

Comment: What if the excess charges given are positive?

Comment: @RifatSafin Then electrons shift in the other direction - into the bulk, leaving positive charges on the surface.